# Android Date.toLocaleString() - without time elements?

Tags: android, datetime

I am using Date.toLocaleString() in my app to get a string representation of the date - I only want the date (ie. Apr 5, 2012) without the time elements, is this possible?

However I achieve this I need it to be multi language so '5/4/2012' is no good as US dates are MM/DD/YYYY rather than DD/MM/YYYY for the UK.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jon, excuse my ignorance but how do I get the timezone information from the device and use it to format the date using your method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [mentioned in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#toLocaleString%28%29), this method is deprecated. Instead, you should use a `DateFormat` (such as `SimpleDateFormat` or the built-in ones) which makes it easy to specify date patterns.

For example:

```
// You can specify styles if you want
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
// Set time zone information if you want.
Date date = ...;
String text = format.format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer your question in the comment by quoting [the Android documentation of DateFormat class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html):

> Most callers should avoid supplying their own format strings to this
>   class' format methods, and rely on the correctly localized ones
>   supplied by the system. **This class' factory methods return
>   appropriately-localized DateFormat instances, suitable for both
>   formatting and parsing dates**. For the canonical documentation of
>   format strings, see SimpleDateFormat.